# How to access specific array value in laravel dd function

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I just need the coordinates from the geolocation based on the address i put in the params. I am using curl for the request.

Here is my curl request

```
        $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=10%20BISHAN%STREET%2013&key='.$key;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        dd($response);
```

I got a response of

```
array:2 [▼
  "results" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "address_components" => array:6 [▶]
      "formatted_address" => "10 Bishan Street 13, Singapore 579795"
      "geometry" => array:3 [▼
        "location" => array:2 [▼
          "lat" => 1.349774
          "lng" => 103.854975
        ]
        "location_type" => "ROOFTOP"
        "viewport" => array:2 [▶]
      ]
      "place_id" => "ChIJR0tGixEX2jERVE4uZWfBN-o"
      "plus_code" => array:2 [▶]
      "types" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
  ]
  "status" => "OK"
]
```

If i do `dd($response['result']);`

I get

```
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "address_components" => array:6 [▶]
    "formatted_address" => "10 Bishan Street 13, Singapore 579795"
    "geometry" => array:3 [▼
      "location" => array:2 [▼
        "lat" => 1.349774
        "lng" => 103.854975
      ]
      "location_type" => "ROOFTOP"
      "viewport" => array:2 [▼
        "northeast" => array:2 [▼
          "lat" => 1.3511229802915
          "lng" => 103.85632398029
        ]
        "southwest" => array:2 [▼
          "lat" => 1.3484250197085
          "lng" => 103.85362601971
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "place_id" => "ChIJR0tGixEX2jERVE4uZWfBN-o"
    "plus_code" => array:2 [▼
      "compound_code" => "8VX3+WX Singapore"
      "global_code" => "6PH58VX3+WX"
    ]
    "types" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "street_address"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Is there a way i can access `location` directly using `dd`?. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: As is a multimensional associative array, you can retrieve `location` with `$dd['response']['geometry']['location']`, this way you have an array with `lat` and `lng` keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the hierarchy, you just add the corresponding array element name at each stage, this should give you...

```
$response['result'][0]['geometry']['location']
```

The `[0]` may need a `foreach` if there are more results.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dd($response['result']['geometry']['location']);
```

Comment: it says `Undefined index: geometry`